# RRULE in android

Tags: android, calendar, icalendar, android-calendar, rrule

I am trying to set weekly monday reminder in calendar at 9 a.m.
Following is the code

```
final int[] preTimings = {9, 12, 18};

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
ContentValues newEvent = new ContentValues();

int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);

calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

for(int i = 0; i < preTimings.length; i++{
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, preTimings[i]);
    long timeInMillis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

    newEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    newEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, preTitle[i]);
    newEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, timeInMillis);                   
    newEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, timeInMillis + 60000);
    newEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO");
    newEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, true);
    newEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "GMT-05:30");
```

So this program is setting the 12 p.m and 6 p.m correctly on Mondays every week but for some reason it is setting the 9 a.m on Tuesdays every week.
I don't know what is wrong over here. I even tried converting the timeInMillis in an online calculator to know what is the result, but they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was on the last line, even though i have specifically declared the timezone, it was setting it incorrectly.

So instead of

```
newEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "GMT-05:30");
```

It should be

```
newEvent.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, String.valueOf(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
```

Still no idea why it worked for times 11 a.m and above. Kinda weird